# How to load page contain ReactJs into other page using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs, single-page-application

I am working on an existing application. I wrote some of its views in React Js. Now I would like to load these views in other page using jquery load. Is that possible.

[Assume leave.html contain react code. Now I want to load leave.html inside index.html using jquery load. index.html has no react code. How to do this]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you can actually use load with react components.But why do you want to use jquery load instead you can use create an element say `div` with `id = "leave"` in your index.html and append your react component let **webpack** compiler take care of parsing it to index.html, code from leave.html can go as as react component in a jsx file such as:

```
  import React from 'react';
  class Leave extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);//if you have properties
    this.state = {};
    this.myFunc= this.myFunc.bind(this); // bind your methods like this.
  }
  myFunc(){

}
render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <!-- Html content to be added over here. -->
             {this.myFunc()}
        </div>
    );
}
}
export default Leave;
```

Create a app.js for your application and append the above exported module into index.html

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Leave from './jsx/Leave.jsx'; //import your module from jsx path.
ReactDOM.render(<Leave/>, document.getElementById('leave')); //append the compile data to index.html.
```

index.html will look like this :

```
<html>
  <body>
   <div id="app"></div>
   <script src = "/build/index.js"></script>
   <!--index.js is build by webpack-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Use webpack to compile react and you will be able to have reusable components in your application.

Thanks